# pvs, vgs and lvs returns... nothing?

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm

I'm new to Rocky Linux. When I installed my Rocky Linux, I've configured the partitions to be LVM. I can tell that it works, because when I run `fdisk -l` I get what I need:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo fdisk -l


Disk /dev/sda: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Disk model: VBOX HARDDISK   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x85c3ed59

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048  2099199  2097152   1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       2099200 41943039 39843840  19G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/rl-root: 17 GiB, 18249416704 bytes, 35643392 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rl-swap: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

However, When I do:

```
sudo bash -c "pvs && vgs && lvs"
```

Or even just

```
sudo pvs
sudo vgs
sudo lvs
```

I simply get nothing.

I tried to:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo lvmdevices --update
  No update for devices file is needed.
```

And I've also uncommented the "`use_devicesfile = 1`" in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`, But that didn't helped.

Also, It's weird but:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo systemctl start lvm2
Failed to start lvm2.service: Unit lvm2.service not found.
```

So what's wrong with my Rocky Linux?

**Update:** It seems that when I uncomment the `use_devicesfile` and set it to 0 [like here](https://serverfault.com/a/1093933) it suddenly returns my `pvs && vgs && lvs` correct data - However I am not sure if that's a solution because I see that on the other question there was no solution as well...:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo bash -c "pvs&&vgs&&lvs"
PV         VG Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
/dev/sda2  rl lvm2 a--  <19.00g    0 
VG #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
rl   1   2   0 wz--n- <19.00g    0 
LV   VG Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
root rl -wi-ao---- <17.00g                                                    
swap rl -wi-ao----   2.00g
```

Rocky 9.1 64bit

---

for @davidgo:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo vgscan -y
Found volume group "rl" using metadata type lvm2
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo lvscan -ay
ACTIVE            '/dev/rl/swap' [2.00 GiB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/rl/root' [<17.00 GiB] inherit
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo bash -c "pvs && vgs && lvs"
PV         VG Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
/dev/sda2  rl lvm2 a--  <19.00g    0 
VG #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
rl   1   2   0 wz--n- <19.00g    0 
LV   VG Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
root rl -wi-ao---- <17.00g                                                    
swap rl -wi-ao----   2.00g
```

Comment: What happens if you break the command down - ie sudo/bin/bash <enter>pvs<enter>vgs<enter>lvs<enter>  ?

Comment: @davidgo If i'll write each one of them separately the result will be the same - simply empty, If that's what you mean. Each one of them - `sudo pvs`, `sudo vgs` and `sudo lvs` is empty (unless i'm using my "solution")

Comment: What happens if (as root) you run "vgscan -y" and "lvscan -ay" and then run your pvs;vgs;lvs equivalent?

Comment: @davidgo I have updated my question with an answer for this because I couldn't type it here (see above). If you ask me to use `su` for this, then I unlocked my root account but i'll unlock it if it's necessary.

Comment: @davidgo I can't believe I say it after a long time of frustration from this problem  but you saved the day and you solved my issue!! thank you very much!!!